# Tagging: How to differentiate "spicy" foods from questions about spices?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This one's been bugging me for a while now and I have yet to think of a good solution.

We have one question tagged `[spiciness]`, another tagged `[hot]`, and a few more tagged `[spices]` even though they aren't really about "spices" per se (fresh chili peppers are not what I would call a spice).

The tag `[hot]` seems way too generic, and something about `[spiciness]` bugs me to no end - perhaps it's just the fact that it's so similar to `[spices]` and could easily become a point of confusion.

But I'm not sure what to put in its place.  I'm talking about questions like [How can you make a sauce less spicy/hot?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/how-can-you-make-a-sauce-less-spicy-hot)  I suppose, in technical terms, that such questions are pretty consistently talking about *capsaicin*, but I have to assume that the majority of people asking questions about it aren't going to *know* that.

So... is there a tag we can use to identify questions that are talking about *"that"* kind of spice/heat?  Do we need one?  Should we just lump it under `[spices]`, or remove any spice-related tags altogether?  Should we borrow from another language and use something like `[picante]` (sounds pretentious, but then again we have `[umami]` now)?

Any other ideas, thoughts, recommendations?

Comment: The English equivalent of "picante" is "piquant" (pronounced PEE-kint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `[spicy-hot]` is appropriately succinct and descriptive enough to cover those things that are, well, spicy hot. The *other* spicy is a little more difficult. Perhaps just a `[spicy]`, `[spice]`, or `[spices]` would suffice?

Comment: For the *other* spicy, I think just `[spices]` is close enough.  I kind of like this one; it's a little silly at first glance, but it'll pop up in the autocomplete for both `[spicy]` and `[hot]`, so it'll be easy to find.

Comment: Yea, `[spices]` would be my preference as well.

Answer (score 2):

To my ear, "spicy" nearly *always* refers to heat from chili peppers. The effect of spices is to make a dish "spiced".

I don't really have a strong opinion about which words are used for tags, but I don't think there would be a lot of confusion if "spicy" or "spiciness" were used to refer to spicy-heat and "spice", "spices", or "spiced" were used to refer to spices. Of course, occasionally someone will err, but that's what retagging is for. I don't think there is some configuration that will eliminate the possibility of error or confusion. That is inherent in the ambiguity of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be a good solution to have the separate tags be "herbs and spices," as one tag and "hot 'n spicy" be another, replacing the current ones? ... or something like that?

Comment: The problem with that is that people are still going to start typing "spic..." for either of those cases, and use the auto completion to just pick "spicy".

Comment: @hobodave: Actually, the auto-completion is a full-text search, not a prefix search.  Try typing "pic" and you'll see the spice tags come up.  Then again, that doesn't guarantee people will actually choose the correct tag.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Learned something new :)